# Spring Boot Integration Tests With @MockBean don't release jdbc connections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, integration-testing, testcontainers

I have a problem with integration tests.

We're using spring boot 1.4.4 + spring batch + testcontainers + postgres.

Each integration test annotated:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = { "integrationtest" })
@SpringBootTest(classes = ServiceApplication.class)
```

The problem is:

Looks like each integration test that contains @MockBean annotation creates a new context.
Each new context creates a new connection pool with a 10 connections.
But previous context doesn't release its connections.

So before each such kind of test I can select connections count from postgres:

```
select sum(numbackends) from pg_stat_database;
```

And see that each test adds 10 new connections.

10th test fails because of 100 connections limit.

Could you advice how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try @DirtiesContext? Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#dirtiescontext)

Comment: do you have some configuration which creates connection pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a combination of annotations + all @MockBean classes calculates some kind of "hash".

Each "hash" creates its own context and spring caches it.
Each contains creates its own connection pool with 10 connections by default.

While all contexts are cached all connection pools hold connections - that's is reason my problem.

As **jusermar10** said you can fix it using @DirtiesContext annotation.